# setText in textbox with infinite loop

Tags: c#

I am writing activity recognition software in realtime. But i can't setText in textbox with infinite loop. I try to search Google but no answer. When, i using "textbox.Text += "ZZZZ", it working but I using "textbox.Text = "ZZZ" ", it not working. I hope someone can point me how to solve

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     for (; ; ){
         Thread.Sleep(20);
         ........process....
         tb_activity = "AAA";
     }
 }
```

Comment: Please clarify the question

Comment: Why would you expect `=` to work? That just sets the entire Text property. And what's wrong with using `+=`?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the new **await** and **async** feature in .Net:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    EndlessTask();
}
async Task EndlessTask()
{
    for(int i = 0; true; i++)
    {
        textBox1.Text = i.ToString();
        await Task.Delay(500);
    }
}
```

[Edit] Note, if you want to get rid of the async warning:

```
#pragma warning disable 4014
EndlessTask();
#pragma warning restore 4014
```

Answer (score 0):

```
i can't setText in textbox with infinite loop
```

you can never confirm that un till unless you debug your application while using the `Thread.Sleep()` in infinite loop.

**Reason:** when you use `Thread.Sleep()` it makes your Main thread to sleep so it is not a good practice to use `Thread.Sleep()` . it hangs your UI therefore you can not see the  Control Updates on the UI like Label Text update ,TextBox Text Update things like that.

ofcourse you call `Application.DoEvents()` to refresh the UI but it is not a good practice as there are many other problems.

**Solution:**  i suggest you to use `Timer` instead of using `Thread.Sleep()` as it runs in the background so it doesnot hang your UI and also you can see the updates on UI.

*Simple Example to show you how to use Timer for updating the Text on Textbox @ certain intervals*

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        int count = 0;
        string text1 = "this is a scrolling text";
        System.Windows.Forms.Timer timer1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();               
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            button1.Enabled = false;
            textBox1.ReadOnly = true;
            SetTimer(500);
        }
        private void SetTimer(int milliseconds)
        {            
            timer1.Tick+=new EventHandler(timer1_Tick);
            timer1.Interval = milliseconds;        
            timer1.Start();
        }
        private void timer1_Tick(Object o, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (count < text1.Length)
            {
                textBox1.Text += text1[count];
                count++;
            }
            else
            {
                timer1.Stop();
                button1.Enabled = true;
                textBox1.ReadOnly = false;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank Sudhakar Tilapudi,  I've tried iSteve Wellens's way and success. I like your explanation. Thank